# Change jbutton icon when spacebar is pressed

Tags: java, jbutton, keyevent

what is wrong here? I want to change the icon of the jbutton when I press the space bar and go back to its original state when I release it

```
               case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                ImageIcon i=new ImageIcon("image/heart.jpg");
                ImageIcon c=new ImageIcon("hug.jpg");
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.PRESS)
                jButton1.setIcon(i);
                else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.RELEASE)
                jButton1.setIcon(c);
               break;
```

Comment: Deducing from the naming, `keyCode` is already proven to be `KeyEvent.VK_SPACE`, so the tests `keyCode == KeyEvent.PRESS` and `keyCode == KeyEvent.RELEASE` make no sense at all.

Comment: I changed it to this but the icon was gone
`case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                ImageIcon i=new ImageIcon("image/heart.jpg");
                jButton1.setIcon(i);
            break;`

Comment: Then, you know that the code did something. Now, you have to check whether the specified icon image can be loaded. Actually, it’s recommended to do this beforehand, at the start of the application and re-use the icon object, instead of loading the image again on every keypress.